# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBalance') in node.js

Tags: node.js, blockchain

I am getting error when using web3.js to get the balance of an account. I am using ganache. My code is below,

```
var Web3 = require("web3");

//connect with ganache
const ganacheWeb3 = new Web3(
  new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545")
);
console.log(ganacheWeb3);

//check the balance of an account
const balanceOfAccount = Web3.Eth.getBalance(
  "0xaEA4e665291fdBFe4bAFc5b81F6F213551180ab5"
);
console.log(
  balanceOfAccount.then((result) =>
    console.log(Web3.utils.fromWei(result, "ether"))
  )
);

Web3.eth.getBalance(
  "0xaEA4e665291fdBFe4bAFc5b81F6F213551180ab5",
  (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(result);
    }
  }
);
```

I have used the normal functional way and callback way. I don't know which one is correct. But still I am getting error. The error is,

```
const balanceOfAccount = Web3.Eth.getBalance(
                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBalance')
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Blockchain Development\Web3.js\intro-to-web3.js\index.js:10:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47
```

I am trying to get the value of an ethereum account. But getting an error.

Comment: change Web3.Eth.getBalance() to Web3.eth.getBalance()

Answer (score 0):

Change `Web3.Eth.getBalance(...)` to `Web3.eth.getBalance(...)`.

Documentation: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#getbalance

Comment: It doesn't work also. I have used async/await. Now it works for me